# How can I choose picture based on the language with nextJS 13 and next intl

Tags: next.js

I am developing my app with NextJS 13.3 and appDir. I would like to choose pictures based on the language. Below is my implementation. But I am not sure whether this is best practice.

```
import imgPL from '/public/images/myImage_pl.png';
import imgEN from '/public/images/myImage_en.png';
import { useLocale } from 'next-intl';

export default function Page() {
  const locale = useLocale();

  return (

    <Image src={locale==='pl' ? imgPL:imgEN} alt="" width={200} />
    
  );
}
```

It seems working but I feel there should be better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks pretty good to me!

Alternatively, if you support many locales, you could also reference the images without an import via:

```
import { useLocale } from 'next-intl';

export default function Page() {
  const locale = useLocale();

  return (
    <Image src={`/images/myImage_${locale}.png` alt="" width={200} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan, this is exactly what I thought. But somehow it does not work. Below is what I have tried to do

Comment: `import { useLocale } from 'next-intl';

const Page = () => {
  const locale = useLocale();

  return (
    <div>
      <Image src={`/${locale}/logo.svg`} alt={''} width={200} height={200} />
    </div>
  );
};
`

Comment: Are you using the i18n middleware for the App Router? If yes, you might want to move your images to a folder like `images` so the resolved path doesn't start with the locale (could be confused with content routes by the middleware depending on your configuration).

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for the reply. Yes I use middleware. Do you mean an `public/images` file for images? What should I add to middleware? It looks like `matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|favicon.ico|assets).*)'],`